# Unreachable Code Java

Tags: java, eclipse, oracle, connection

I'm trying to make oracle connection but when i write the connection string eclipse gives me unreachable code error can you help me?

This is where im using connection class

```
package com.service;

import java.sql.*;

import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/Aut")
public class Authentication {
    @POST
    @Path("/Login")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String Login(String params){
        System.out.println("params : " + params);

        String[] tempArray= params.split("&");

        String uname=tempArray[0].split("=")[1];
        String upass=tempArray[1].split("=")[1];

        System.out.println("uname : " + uname);
        System.out.println("upass : " + upass);

        if(uname.equals("ozzy") && upass.equals("123456"))
        {
            return "Success";
            db dd=new db();
            db.dbconnect();

        }else{
            return "Failed";
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my connection class

```
    package com.service;

    import java.sql.*;
    public class db{
        public static void dbconnect(){
            try{
                Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
                Connection con = null;
                con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:SID","username","password");
                con.close();

                Statement stmt=con.createStatement();

                ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from emp");
                while(rs.next())
                System.out.println(rs.getInt(1)+"  "+rs.getString(2)+"  "+rs.getString(3));

                con.close();

            }catch(Exception e){ System.out.println(e);}

        }
    }
```

Thanks for help :)

Comment: You are using `eclipse`, which is an _integrated development environment_ that is able to __show__ you _where_ your error is. And there are at least a dozen of questions here on SO explaining what this compiler error means and good explanations on how to get rid of it. Using a seach engine and a little bit of thinking would have brought a solution to your problem withing minutes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a statement

```
        return "Success";
```

here

```
if(uname.equals("ozzy") && upass.equals("123456"))
{
        return "Success";
        db dd=new db();
        db.dbconnect();
}
```

obviously the remaining code can't be executed.

> More specifically a return statement ends the execution of a method,
>   as such any code put after the return will not execute and is
>   "unreachable'

Comment: More specifically a return statement ends the execution of a method, as such any code put after the return will not execute and is "unreachable'.